# How can I write to an AVAssetWriter my custom float / shorts array?

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, avassetwriter

So i used `AVAssetReader` got the `CMSampleBufferRef`and then i got the samples values from `CMBlockBufferRef` data.

I then changed this samples with a custom filter.

Now i have an array of Shorts which i want to write back to a file, using AVAssetWriter.

My question here is how do I create back a  `CMSampleBufferRef`  and a `CMBlockBufferRef` to send to the AVAssetWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [apple developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html).

**EDIT:**
Based on your comments, to create a samplebuffer directly from a shorts array, you should use Core Media Framework components, i.e. [CMSampleBufferCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/index.html)

1. Convert sample data in shorts array to AudioBufferList
2. Convert the AudioBufferList to a CMSampleBuffer.

For example:

```
OSStatus status = noErr;
CMItemCount framesToProcess = 8192;
unsigned long sizeInBytes = framesToProcess * sizeof(SInt16);

// Init ABL from sample array
AudioBufferList *myAudioBufferList; // contains converted
myAudioBufferList = static_cast<AudioBufferList *>(calloc(1, offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers) + (sizeof(AudioBuffer))));
myAudioBufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
myAudioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
myAudioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = JoãoSamplesArrayPointer;
myAudioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)sizeInBytes;

// sampleBuffer in (from the assetreader) you already have this
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferIn = [self.assetReaderAudioOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBufferIn);
const AudioStreamBasicDescription *assetReaderOutputASBD = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(format);

// setup output samplebuffer
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferOut = NULL;
CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, sampleRate), kCMTimeZero, kCMTimeInvalid };

// create description
status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, assetReaderOutputASBD, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &format);

// create buffer
CMSampleBufferCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, framesToProcess, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &sampleBufferOut);

// put data into buffer from ABL (audio buffer list)
status = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList( sampleBufferOut, kCFAllocatorDefault,  kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, myAudioBufferList );

// write to assetwriter audioinput
BOOL success = [self.assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBufferOut];
CFRelease(sampleBufferOut);
```

Comment: I understand this code. But this is not what i am asking

Comment: What are you asking more specifically? I tried to address the  issue of creating a CMSampleBufferRef as shown in the code.

Comment: I need to create the sample buffer from my shorts array and not from the asset reader

Comment: This looks better. I will give it a try next week. Also my shorts array is not a complete one, but one done kinda in real time. I will have an arrray then a bit more then more. Till i have a complete one. But i guess i will just use this code to start :)